Typescript LSP not attaching to buffer
I have been using make the Typescript LSP to work with my JS/TS files but I keep getting an error of the following nature when I run
:LspLog:
[ERROR][2024-06-18 21:41:58] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:734    "rpc"   "/home/temo/.local/share/nvim/mason/bin/typescript-language-server" "stderr"    "node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1215\n throw err;\n ^\n\nError: Cannot find module '/home/tirivashe/.local/share/nvim/mason/typescript-language-server/lib/cli.mjs'\n  at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1212:15)\n  at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1038:27)\n  at wrapModuleLoad (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:212:19)\n  at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:158:5)\n  at node:internal/main/run_main_module:30:49 {\n code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',\n requireStack: []\n}\n\nNode.js v22.3.0\n"

I've searched the entire internet and I can't seem to find a suitable solution. This is also affecting other LSPs like Tailwind and CSS modules, CSS etc, where each cannot find their particular modules. But other LSPs like for Go or Lua are working fine, with their default configs. Anybody got some ideas on how to solve this?
I am using the LazyVim setup, on WSL, Ubuntu distribution.
I've already tried using the LazyVim options, some other configs online, but didn't have much success on that

For me for some reason there's no directory /home/$USER/.local/share/nvim/mason/typescript-language-server.
And after searching for a bit, i found a /lib/cli.mjs in /home/$USER/.local/share/nvim/mason/packages/typescript-language-server/node_modules/typescript-language-server/lib/cli.mjs.
So, i just made a symlink to it
ln -s /home/$USER/.local/share/nvim/mason/packages/typescript-language-server/node_modules/typescript-language-server /home/$USER/.local/share/nvim/mason/typescript-language-server

I don't know what the actual problem nor the better solution is.
But for now, it works for me.
